# XCode : Unable to distribute flutter adhoc build due to app thinning error

Tags: flutter, xcode, rubygems, archive, ad-hoc-distribution

I am attempting to create an ad hoc build of my flutter app in XCode but when I distribute the app ad hoc I get the following error. (Pictured below)
[image: Error when distributing app for ad hoc]
Upon further investigating I checked the verbose log and found the following:

> 2023-04-22 17:28:24 +0000  Output: ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin22]
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/AppThinning.framework/Resources/ipatool:4135: warning: assigned but unused variable - prev
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/CFPropertyList-2.3.6/lib/cfpropertylist/rbCFPropertyList.rb:99: warning: assigned but unused variable - temp
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'x86_64,arm64e', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle' (no such file), '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'x86_64,arm64e', need 'arm64')) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle (LoadError)
>
> Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle (LoadError)
> from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date.rb:4:in` <top (required)>'
> from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
> from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/CFPropertyList-2.3.6/lib/cfpropertylist/rbCFPropertyList.rb:4:in `<top (required)>' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
> from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/CFPropertyList-2.3.6/lib/cfpropertylist.rb:3:in` <top (required)>'
> from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in `require' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in` rescue in require'
> from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require' from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/AppThinning.framework/Resources/ipatool:15:in` '
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- cfpropertylist (LoadError)

I have unistalled and reinstalled XCode deleted the deprived data and this:
Step 1: Clean DerivedData & Also remove it from Trash
Step 2: Delete POD folder from iOS Folder
Step 3: Delete Pod.lock file
Step 4: Flutter Clean
Step 5: Flutter pub get
Step 6: pod deintegrate
Step 7: pod install
Now try to run app & then again make new build, do archive & distribute app.
Any insight would be appreciated. I am attaching the verbose log.
https://pastebin.com/tPSBq8zB